# Is there a way to use multi-finger gesture controls using a multi-touch touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, gnome-shell, 20.04, multi-touch

Is there a way to use multi-finger gesture controls using a multi-touch touchpad in Ubuntu 20.04? Windows has this feature built-in which is extremely convenient for laptop users. I have tried [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci6YbQGx3c4) and [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1253/extended-gestures/) but they didn't work!

Comment: The specific touchpad device that you have will determine the driver needed, and the manufacturer for your device may or may not provide a Linux driver.  As long as your device is supported, you should be able to adjust touchpad settings in system settings.  This is going to be different depending on what DE you use.  KDE/Kubuntu, for example, has a lot of options ranging from number of fingers, sensitivity, disable touchpad when typing, etc.  Please research the driver needed for your hardware device and perhaps try out another flavor "live" to find out what works best with your device.

Comment: @Nmath I am asking how can I enable this in Ubuntu? It is easy enough in windows. I can't find where I can enable this in settings.

Answer (score 0):

synclient is a application for the command line to control synaptics touchpad driver There used to be a gui-program to called Synaptics or so, where you could control regions and sensitivity for the touchpad. In gnome settings  and in gnome tweaks there are some settings for the periferial...
You could open a terminal shell and type the command:
   'man 1 synclient'
and see what gives, or
   'synclient --help'